# MediaPlayer gives different results if it has to wait longer before .start() is called

Tags: android, performance, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to use a `MediaPlayer` instance to play several audio files individually, in response to various sensor events.

I've found that when I load up the clip to be played right before calling `MediaPlayer.start()`, the audio clip will play fine. However, the application takes a major performance hit. Ideally, each audio clip should be loaded into the MediaPlayer immediately after the last one was played, leaving the MediaPlayer ready to start playback the instant the `SensorEvent` comes in.

I would expect this to be simple, but now that I made the change the audio just doesn't play. `PlayAudioClip()` is definitely still being called as expected, but something is going wrong after that. No errors are thrown, so I don't think the MediaPlayer is changing state, but could something be interfering with in the time that it's waiting to play?

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    private Random numGenerator;
    private SensorManager manager;
    private Sensor accelerometer;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Uri[] audioClips;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initVariables();
        prepareNextAudioClip(); //load first audioClip

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            if(conditionsRight()){
                playAudioClip();
            }
        }
    }

    private void playAudioClip() {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        prepareNextAudioClip();
    }

    private void prepareNextAudioClip() {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            Uri audioClip = audioclips[(int) Math.floor(numGenerator.nextDouble()*audioClips.length)];
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, audioClip);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


//Code below here isn't very important... handling setup and teardown

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {}

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        manager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
       }

    private void initVariables() {
        audioClips = new Uri[]{
                Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.afraidofflying/" + R.raw.audio1),
                Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.afraidofflying/" + R.raw.audio2),
                Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.afraidofflying/" + R.raw.audio3)
        };
        numGenerator = new Random();
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        manager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        if(null == accelerometer) finish();
    }

     protected void onPause() {
         super.onPause();
         manager.unregisterListener(this);
     }


    protected void onDestroy(){
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }

}
```

**PS:** This has all been assuming I'll only use one instance of MediaPlayer but I'd also like input on if you think using multiple MediaPlayers and delegating each of them 1 audio clip would be advisable. My intuition is no because for my purposes I'd have to use 10-20 MediaPlayers, but it would be good to hear outside perspectives on it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're resetting player right after starting playback.

```
private void playAudioClip() {
    mediaPlayer.start(); //starting playback
    prepareNextAudioClip(); //reset
}
```

if you want to play files in queue, than you can use one instance. But if you have to play several files simultaneusly, then you need to have several media player instances.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to look at subtle points regarding using Mediaplayer class

In your code you used:

```
initVariables();
prepareNextAudioClip(); //load first audioClip
```

initVariables() seems ok, Now lets see  prepareNextAudioClip()

```
...
mediaPlayer.reset();
...
...
mediaPlayer.prepare();
```

The above code seems to corrupt Mediaplayer state machine. Please refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html for details on using new, prepare,reset. It is better to write defensive MediaPlayer code using Errorlistener